# Force execution of pattern rules when the target is not explicitly used

Tags: makefile, rule-engine

I have a Makefile which takes care of downloading a few javascript files needed as a prerequisite for `r.js`

For each of them I've created a `.url` file which contains the url where the `.js` file can be downloaded, and set up a pattern rule like this:

```
static/js/lib/%.js: jslibsurls/%.url
    curl -L -s -o $@ `cat $<`
```

but it only downloads a `.js` file if it is an explicit dependency somewhere in the Makefile...

Is there any way to make the pattern rule to be executed if there's a dependency matching it even if the target is not used yet (they will be used in wildcard once they are created)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it, I need to do a `patsubst` with the names of the `.url` files to create the `.js` and use the result as the dependency to a phoney rule that I can then use as dependency for the `r.js` step.

```
DOWNLOADED_LIBS+=$(patsubst jslibsurls/%.url,static/js/lib/%.js,$(wildcard jslibsurls/*.url))

download-libs: $(DOWNLOADED_LIBS)

#this downloads a .js in static/js/lib/ file for each .url file in jslibsurls/
static/js/lib/%.js: jslibsurls/%.url
    curl -L -s -o $@ `cat $<`

.PHONY: download-libs
```